# Put a table below corresponding plot in a 4 by 4 layout - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm still building a shiny dashboard.
I want to display some graphs displaying 2 graphs in a row. And I managed to do that as in the screenshot
[image]

Now below each graph I want to add a small table with summary statics while **mantaining the 4 by 4 layout as in the previous plot**. When I tried to do that this is the result

[image]

Here's my ui.R scripts..

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title= "Acquisti Clienti "),
  dashboardSidebar(
      h4("Explorer"),
      textInput("cluster","Digita un Codice cliente :","H0111"),
      selectizeInput('categ',label="Seleziona una Categoria Merceologica",
                     choices=unique(user_clustering$DESC_CAT_MERC),
                     selected=c("NOTEBOOK","PC","TABLET/PDA"),
                     options = NULL,
                     multiple=TRUE),
      uiOutput("checkcluster"),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
      menuItem("Data", tabName = "Data")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("Spesa_Grafico",width=3),
                valueBoxOutput("Spesa_Totale",width=3),
                valueBoxOutput("Spesa_Cluster",width=3),
                valueBoxOutput("Clienti_Cluster",width=3)
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotlyOutput('plot1')),
                DT::dataTableOutput("plot1_data",width = 8),
                box(plotlyOutput('plot2')),
                DT::dataTableOutput("plot2_data",width = 8),
                box(plotlyOutput('plot3')),
                DT::dataTableOutput("plot3_data",width = 8),
                box(plotlyOutput('plot4')),
                DT::dataTableOutput("plot4_data",width = 8)

              )

              )
      ,
      tabItem("Data",
              DT::dataTableOutput("Data"),
              downloadButton("downloadCsv", "Download as CSV")
      ))
    )
  )
```

Here is server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame


  # Radar Chart data
  selectedData <- reactive({

    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    data_plot<- user_clustering_raw %>%filter(DESC_CAT_MERC %in% categ)%>%
                group_by(CLUSTER,DESC_CAT_MERC)%>%
                dplyr::summarise(VAL_INV=sum(VAL_INV))%>%ungroup()

    data_plot$VAL_INV<-data_plot$VAL_INV/sum(data_plot$VAL_INV)


    return (data_plot)
  })

  # RFM chart (2nd page....)
  selectedData_plot2<-reactive({
    clust<-selectedData()$clust
    RFM_rec <- RFM_rec %>% 
      inner_join(user_clustering_raw%>%select(CO_CUST,CLUSTER)%>%distinct(),by="CO_CUST")%>%
      filter(CLUSTER %in% clust)
    return (RFM_rec)

  })

  # Data for summary alongside graph
  summary_1<-reactive({
    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    summary_1<-user_clustering_raw%>%
                         filter(DESC_CAT_MERC%in% categ)
    return (summary_1)
  })


  # output$Spesa_Grafico <- renderValueBox({
  # 
  #   d<-summary_1()
  #   valueBox(
  #     value = paste(as.character(round((d$TOP_7_SOMMA/d$SOMMA_VAL_INV)[1]*100,2)),"%"),
  #     subtitle = "% Spesa Grafico",
  #     icon = icon("area-chart"),
  #     color =  "aqua"
  #   )
  # })

  output$Spesa_Totale <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = prettyNum(round(sum(user_clustering$VAL_INV),0),big.mark=",",decimal.mark = "."),
      subtitle = "Spesa Totale",
      icon = icon("euro")
    )
  })

  # output$Spesa_Cluster <- renderValueBox({
  #   d<-summary_1()
  #   valueBox(
  #     prettyNum(round(d$TOP_7_SOMMA[1],0),big.mark=",",decimal.mark = "."),
  #     "Spesa Cluster",
  #     icon = icon("euro")
  #   )
  # })

  output$Clienti_Totali <- renderValueBox({


    valueBox(
      length(unique(user_clustering_raw%>%pull(CO_CUST))),
      "Numero Clienti Totali",
      icon = icon("users")
    )
  })



  summary_2<-reactive({

    data_summary_2<-user_clustering_raw%>%filter(CLUSTER==selectedData()$clust)%>%
      filter(DESC_CAT_MERC%in%selectedData()$cat_merc)%>%
      group_by(CO_CUST)%>%
      summa#%>%mutate(VAL_INV=prettyNum(round(VAL_INV,0),big.mark = ","))

    outlier<-data.frame(CO_CUST=attributes(big_outliers),FLAG_OUTLIER=1)
    colnames(outlier)<-c("CO_CUST","FLAG_OUTLIER")

    data_summary_2<- data_summary_2%>%left_join(outlier,by="CO_CUST")%>%
      replace_na(list(FLAG_OUTLIER=0))

    colnames(data_summary_2)<-c("Codice Cliente", "Categoria Merc.",
                                "Spesa (EUR)","Cluster","Outlier") 
    data_summary_2

  })


  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    d1<-selectedData()
    d1_clust<-d1%>%filter(DESC_CAT_MERC %in% categ)

    d1_clust<-d1_clust%>%filter(CLUSTER==1)

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      r = d1_clust$VAL_INV,
      theta = d1_clust$DESC_CAT_MERC,
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,1)
          )
        ),
        showlegend = F, title="Cluster 1"
      )


   })

  output$plot1_data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    plot1_data<-summary_1()

    plot1_data<-plot1_data%>%filter(CLUSTER==1)%>%
                group_by(DESC_CAT_MERC)%>%
                summarise(VAL_INV=sum(VAL_INV),NUMERICA_CLIENTI=n_distinct(CO_CUST))


    DT::datatable(plot1_data,rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom = 't'))
  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    d1<-selectedData()
    d2_clust<-d1%>%filter(DESC_CAT_MERC %in% categ)

    d2_clust<-d2_clust%>%filter(CLUSTER==2)

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      r = d2_clust$VAL_INV,
      theta = d2_clust$DESC_CAT_MERC,
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,1)
          )
        ),
        showlegend = F,title="Cluster 2"
      )


  })

  output$plot2_data <- DT::renderDataTable({

    plot2_data<-summary_1()

    plot2_data<-plot2_data%>%filter(CLUSTER==2)%>%
      group_by(DESC_CAT_MERC)%>%
      summarise(VAL_INV=sum(VAL_INV),NUMERICA_CLIENTI=n_distinct(CO_CUST))


    DT::datatable(plot2_data,rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom = 't'))
  })


  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    d1<-selectedData()
    d3_clust<-d1%>%filter(DESC_CAT_MERC %in% categ)
    d3_clust<-d3_clust%>%filter(CLUSTER==3)

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      r = d3_clust$VAL_INV,
      theta = d3_clust$DESC_CAT_MERC,
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,1)
          )
        ),
        showlegend = F,title="Cluster 3"
      )


  })

  output$plot3_data <- DT::renderDataTable({

    plot3_data<-summary_1()

    plot3_data<-plot3_data%>%filter(CLUSTER==3)%>%
      group_by(DESC_CAT_MERC)%>%
      summarise(VAL_INV=sum(VAL_INV),NUMERICA_CLIENTI=n_distinct(CO_CUST))


    DT::datatable(plot3_data,rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom = 't'))
  })

  output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({

    categ<-input[["categ"]]
    d1<-selectedData()
    d4_clust<-d1%>%filter(DESC_CAT_MERC %in% categ)
    d4_clust<-d4_clust%>%filter(CLUSTER==3)

    plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      r = d4_clust$VAL_INV,
      theta = d4_clust$DESC_CAT_MERC,
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      layout(
        polar = list(
          radialaxis = list(
            visible = T,
            range = c(0,1)
          )
        ),
        showlegend = F,title="Cluster 4"
      )


  })
  output$plot4_data <- DT::renderDataTable({

    plot4_data<-summary_1()

    plot4_data<-plot4_data%>%filter(CLUSTER==4)%>%
      group_by(DESC_CAT_MERC)%>%
      summarise(VAL_INV=sum(VAL_INV),NUMERICA_CLIENTI=n_distinct(CO_CUST))


    DT::datatable(plot4_data,rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom = 't'))
  })

  # output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
  #   
  #   d<-selectedData_plot2()
  #   adding_point<- d[d$CO_CUST==input$cluster,]
  #   p1 <-  ggplot(d,aes(x=FREQ))+
  #     geom_histogram(fill="darkblue",col="white")+
  #     ggtitle("Frequenza Acquisti")+labs(x="Frequenza Acquisti",y="Conteggio")+
  #     geom_point(x=adding_point$FREQ,y=0,col="red",size=4)+
  #     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=12),
  #           axis.title.x = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
  #   
  #   breaks <- pretty(range(d$MONET), n = nclass.FD(d$MONET), min.n = 1)
  #   bwidth <- breaks[2]-breaks[1]
  #   p2 <-  ggplot(d,aes(x=round(MONET,0)))+
  #     geom_histogram(fill="darkblue",col="white")+
  #     ggtitle("Valore Monetario Acquisti (EUR)")+labs(x="Valore Monetario",y="Conteggio")+
  #     scale_x_continuous(labels=dollar_format(prefix="€"))+
  #     geom_point(x=adding_point$MONET,y=0,col="red",size=4)+
  #     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=12),
  #           axis.title.x = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
  #   
  #   p3 <-  ggplot(d,aes(x=LAST_PURCHASE))+
  #     geom_histogram(fill="darkblue",col="white")+
  #     ggtitle("Ultimo Acquisto (Giorni)")+labs(x="Ultimo Acquisto",y="Conteggio")+
  #     geom_point(x=adding_point$LAST_PURCHASE,y=0,col="red",size=4)+
  #     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45,hjust=1,size=12),
  #           axis.title.x = element_blank(),plot.title = element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
  #   
  #   grid.arrange(p1, p2,p3, nrow = 1)   
  # },height = 510)

  output$Data <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(summary_2(),rownames = FALSE)%>% formatStyle(
      'Outlier',
      target = 'row',
      color =  styleEqual(c(1, 0), c('red', 'black')))%>%formatCurrency(3:3, '')
  })


  output$checkcluster <- renderUI({
    if (sum(input$cluster%in% user_clustering_raw$CO_CUST)==0)
      print ("Errore! Codice Cliente non presente...")})

}
```

Comment: You haven't provided code for the server. Also, please clarify what you want, given result outputs table under the image, isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: yes. Table below each graph while mantaining the  4 by 4 layout as in the first screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest putting plot and table output within `verticalLayout` and pair (row of two layouts) putting within `column`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
    column(3, offset = 2, verticalLayout(plotlyOutput("p1"), dataTableOutput("d1"))),
    column(3, offset = 2, verticalLayout(plotlyOutput("p2"), dataTableOutput("d2"))),
    column(3, offset = 2, verticalLayout(plotlyOutput("p3"), dataTableOutput("d3"))),
    column(3, offset = 2, verticalLayout(plotlyOutput("p4"), dataTableOutput("d4")))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$p1 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp)
    })
    output$d1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(head(mtcars))
    })
    output$p2 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp)
    })
    output$d2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(head(mtcars))
    })
    output$p3 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp)
    })
    output$d3 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(head(mtcars))
    })
    output$p4 <- renderPlotly({
        plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~disp)
    })
    output$d4 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(head(mtcars))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I found another solution that involve the use of fluidrow inside a box

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. Putting table inside `box` and adjusting with the use of `column` and `fluidRow`

Modifying my original post :

```
fluidRow(
                box(title="Cluster 1",plotlyOutput('plot1'),
                    fluidRow(column(4,offset=3,DT::dataTableOutput("plot1_data",width = 8)))),
                #DT::dataTableOutput("plot1_data",width = 8),
                box(title="Cluster 2",plotlyOutput('plot2'),
                    fluidRow(column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("plot2_data",width = 8)))),
                #DT::dataTableOutput("plot2_data",width = 8),
                box(title="Cluster 3",plotlyOutput('plot3'),
                    fluidRow(column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("plot3_data",width = 8)))),
                #DT::dataTableOutput("plot3_data",width = 8),
                box(title="Cluster 4",plotlyOutput('plot4'),
                    fluidRow(column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("plot4_data",width = 8))))
```